# SQL CASE Catch and Return Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am building a trigger to do some calculations for me. However, I am just writing the commands to see if they work for right now and produce error handling. So I have written the following code.

```
DECLARE @strTotalAssets varchar(8000)

SELECT @strTotalAssets = (SELECT ProjectOther2 FROM
            Project WHERE ProjectID = '00000:')

SELECT 
    CASE
      WHEN RIGHT(value, 1) = 'M' THEN LEFT(value, (LEN(value)-1)) * 1000000
      WHEN RIGHT(value, 1) = 'T' THEN LEFT(value, (LEN(value)-1)) * 1000
      WHEN RIGHT(value, 1) > 0 THEN RETURN 'Error: You forgot to put a mutliplier Value'
      ELSE 'Error'
    END
FROM Split(@strTotalAssets, '|')
```

The problem I have is that I do not know how to exit the script and return an error. Forgive my ignorance but just starting out at a jr DBA. Hopefully from the code you can see what I am trying to do. Basically if the user forgot to put a letter value which represents a multiplier of Thousands or Millions which means the value returns only an integer then produce an error and tell the user they forgot to put a value.

Comment: a quick google search: http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&site=&source=hp&q=sql%20server%20error%20handling&aq=0&aqi=g5&aql=&oq=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=5e700cf850b50a47&pf=p&pdl=300&safe=active

Comment: Since you are clearly headed this way, I want to point out that you NEVER under any circumstances write a trigger to assume only one row is being processed in SQl Server. So your code will not work when you consider that more than one record might need to be processed at one time. You need to think in terms of sets of data especially in triggers.

Comment: Thanks, I did take this into consideration after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for GOTO Error.  [Here's a quick primer](http://www.novicksoftware.com/tipsandtricks/tips-erorr-handling-in-a-stored-procedure.htm).  I only skimmed it quickly, but it looked pretty good for what you need.

Comment: Thanks, I will review it shortly and respond accordingly

Answer (score 2):

As this is a trigger, returning data in the true sense isnt an option; for something thats treated in the same way as say a key violation error and returned to the client in the same fashion you can [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx):

```
RAISERROR('You forgot to put a mutliplier Value', 15, 121)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct as well, however I eliminated a lot of code by not writing my own ifs, and utilizing built in SQL code. I was able to capture the fact SQL threw an error then just returned the error.